# Rotation angle of an eigenvector basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, vectors

Suppose I have a matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2}$ and I have computed its eigenvectors ${\bf{b}}_1$ and ${\bf{b}}_2$. How can I find the angle $\theta$ to which these eigenvectors are rotated to?

I want to find this because following [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid#As_quadric) I have found the principal axes of an ellipse and would now like to know the angle $\theta$ at which this ellipse is rotated to (wrt positive $x$ axis).

Comment: An idea would be to compute the dot product with one of the standard basis vectors ${\bf{b}}_1^\top {\bf{e}}_1 = \parallel {\bf{b}}_1\parallel \, \parallel {\bf{e}}_1\parallel \cos\theta_1$. However how do we know whether we should consider $\theta_1$ or $\theta_2$? (i.e. the angle with ${\bf{e}_2}$)

Comment: Essentially we would have 
$$
\cos\theta_1 = \frac{{\bf{v}}_1^\top {\bf{e}}_1}{\parallel {\bf{v}}_1\parallel}
$$
and
$$
\cos\theta_2 = \frac{{\bf{v}}_1^\top {\bf{e}}_2}{\parallel {\bf{v}}_1\parallel}
$$

Comment: You can use the sign of the second component of $\mathbf v_1$ to determine whether $0 \leq \theta \leq 180^\circ$ or $180^\circ \leq \theta \leq 360^\circ$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann this doesn't seem to work

Comment: What do you mean when you say it doesn't work? What goes wrong?